# Creating stacked barchart in dc js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to make a stacked barchart in dc js using a group split by name and a date dimension

a date dimension:

```
var date_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return  d.date;});
```

and some numerical data that is grouped by a name

```
var names_grouping = names_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d){
  return d.dep_var
})
```

I have previously used the same grouping, and a grouping by quarters to successfully produce a pie chart showing share of the numerical data by name :

[image]

Code to produce the pie chart:

```
var namechart = dc.pieChart('#sales-by-nameplate')
namechart 
    .width(200)
    .height(200)
    .radius(80)
    .innerRadius(30)
    .dimension(names_dim)
    .group(name_grouping)
    .renderLabel(false);
```

names_dim is this:

```
var names_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Given that the data is already grouped by name, is it possible to create a stacked area chart using the existing name group and date dimension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating stacked charts in dc js with panel dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630651/creating-stacked-charts-in-dc-js-with-panel-dataset)

Answer (score 2):

You mean barchart right (last sentence) ?

You can use the stack method but I guess you want to group by date_dim instead :

```
barChart
   .dimension(date_dim)
   .group(date_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.names_dim === 'Name 1' ? 1 : 0; }), "Name 1")
   .stack(date_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.names_dim === 'Name 2' ? 1 : 0; }), "Name 2")
   .stack(date_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.names_dim === 'Name 3' ? 1 : 0; }), "Name 3")
```

With as many stacks as the number of different names.

Comment: Just tried this but it did the same thing, produced no error but also no chart. Would this signal perhaps that the grouping isn't selecting any data?

Comment: To answer that, set a breakpoint on the chart initialization, after the groups are created. Run `group.all()` in the debug console and see whether the keys and values make sense.