# Creating stacked charts in dc js with panel dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm having trouble creating a stacked barchart, I cannot figure out how to properly apply the dimensions to a panel dataset

My data looks like this:

```
Date     name   value
12/1/15 name1  5
12/1/15 name2  6
12/1/15 name3  2

13/1/15 name1  2
13/1/15 name2  7
13/1/15 name3  8

14/1/15 name1  2
14/1/15 name2  5
14/1/15 name3  10
```

Stored in JSON format

I would like to create stacked charts that plot the values associated with the different names over time.

As I understand dc-js I need to provide a chart with the date dimension, and then another dimension by the different names which then groups the values, however I am unsure how to proceed.

Does anyone know how I can do this with?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to produce the group, from [the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#what-if-rows-contain-a-single-value-but-a-different-value-per-row):

```
var group = dimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) + v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        p[v.type] -= v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // initial
        return {};
    });
```

(In your case, `v.name` instead of `v.type`.)

Basically you create a group which reduces to objects containing the values for each stack.

Then use the name and accessor parameters of `.group()` and `.stack()`. Unfortunately you have to spell it out, as the first has to be `.group` and the rest `.stack`.

As so:

```
chart.group(group, 'name1', function(d) { return d.name1; })
   .stack(group, 'name2', function(d) { return d.name2; })
   .stack(group, 'name3', function(d) { return d.name3; })
   ...
```

(Somewhere on SO or the web is a loop form of this, but I can't find it ATM.)